# Hiding the source of Instanced object in dupliface method

Tags: modifiers, instances, dupli-groups

so, i have ton of high poly phones i want to instance.
so my solution is using dupliface, using another object to instance another object.

[image]

but as you can see, my source object is also in the same place as the instanced object, which results in geometry being in exactly the same place and overlapping each other.

[image]

but when i try to just hide everything in the outliner, the instanced object also disappear.

[image][image]

is there a way to just hide the source of the instanced object, so it only shows the instanced object ?

i hope i explained it correctly

thankyou

Comment: it is quite weird for me, your screen doesn't contain icons for Global and Render visibility ... hm

Comment: The source object should not be visible in render, what does it give if you keep the render option (and disable the preview display)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Object properties > Instancing

With classic instancing (object parented to a grid with *Instancing* enabled under *Object properties > Instancing > Vertices*), there is not a way to hide it, so you have two options with that ...

- in *Edit* mode move whole grid vertices to aside (because instances are generated based on instances origin position) ... that is not so nice for manipulation or animation (but you can add Empty to manipulate from its origin).

[image]

- ... or just Delete the center vertex and keep instanced (phone) as a part of result ...

[image]

---

**Note:** If you don't mind you can use also **Particle System** > *Hair* > Emit from *Vertices*

Comment: yes, i tried this, but still, in the render everything disappears

Comment: Sorry ... my bad ... edited.

Comment: ahh i see, i understand, you're right the instancing i used is quite old school.
should start transitioning to a newer method like geo nodes
nice solution ! thankyou

Comment: You'r welcomed :) Nothing bad with old school I like it it is easier, it has just this glitch :)

Answer (score 1):

### Geometry Nodes - Instancing

If GN would be an option for you ... you can instance by this simple setup ... just assign this GN modifier to your grid and as object use your phone (or collection of objects).

[image]

Or you can select phone object and under GN add Primitive > Grid and let instance phone object.

Comment: yes, i think i should use more geo nodes. Thankyou